# Bash - Remove line based on length of first word

Tags: linux, bash

I need to delete lines (in a text file) that start with a word that is less than 4 characters. In the example **The quick brown fox** gets removed since the first word is only three characters in length.

Before:

```
The quick brown
quick brown fox
brown fox quick
```

After:

```
quick brown fox
brown fox quick
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**preprocess.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{                        \
  if(length($1) >= 4)    \
  {                      \
    printf $0"\n";       \
  }                      \
}
```

**output**

```
$ ./preprocess.awk input.txt 
quick brown fox
brown fox quick
```